# if the is_default column in database is 1 fill the checkbox

Tags: jquery, laravel, checkbox

I want to fill checkbox using jQuery when the is_default column in database is 1.
So I get info from backend using getJSON() for check something like if the mobile number id was equal with data-id in input tag fill the check box.

For example my customer has 2 mobile numbers and I want just send sms to 1 number of it, so I want to show which mobile number is default using API and Laravel and jQuery.

```js
var tbody = '';
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    tbody += '<tr>';
    tbody += '<td><div class="form-group"><div class="checkbox checkbox-primary"><input data-id="' + value.id + '" id="checkbox1" type="checkbox"><label for="checkbox1"></label></div></div></td>;'
    tbody += '</tr>';
});
$('tbody').append(tbody);
 
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8000/api/customers/mobile-numbers/checkbox/" + getID() + "", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        if (value.id === $('input#checkbox1').data('id')) {
            $('input#checkbox1').prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
});
```

in the above code fill all checkbox, but I want to fill only the default mobile number. Something like this below code

```js
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8000/api/customers/mobile-numbers/checkbox/" + getID() + "", function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        if (value.id === $('input#checkbox1').data('id')) {
            $('input#checkbox1').data('id').prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
});
```

[image]

I want something like above code, but I get error that can't reading .prop after .data

thanks for your helping

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little uncertain about what you are asking, but you are doing a check to see if you should update the data, in the if statement you are still getting the data('id') that is unnecessary as it is already checked in the if statement.

Wouldn't this version suffice?

```
if (value.id === $('input#checkbox1').data('id')) {
    $('input#checkbox1').prop('checked', true);
}
```